# Bitmap from ImageReader always blank when trying to capture screen

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image, bytebuffer, android-mediaprojection

Using the MediaProjection API for screen capture, I create an ImageReader and feed use it as a point of access for captured screens as below:

`mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);`

and

```
mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    image = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage();
                    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                    Buffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer().rewind();
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
                }
            });
```

But the resulting image is always a blank transparent image and all pixels in the resulting bitmap are set to #00000000 :(

I've been stuck on this for a while and could really use some help so any advice is welcome. (Also I've already tried these posts but its all the same result - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545970/take-a-screenshot-using-mediaprojection), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219799/system-error-capturing-the-output-of-a-mediaprojection-virtual-display-to-an-ima) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673127/android-imagereader-acquirelatestimage-returns-invalid-jpg))

Edit:
I pass the image reader surface in this line:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int density = metrics.densityDpi;
int flags = DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC;
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
mWidth = size.x;
mHeight = size.y;

mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("screencap", mWidth, mHeight, density, flags, mImageReader.getSurface(), null, mHandler);
```

Comment: Can you show the media projection setup, e.g. the place where you pass the ImageReader Surface in?

Comment: @fadden Ive edited the question to show this now

Comment: Ah never mind. The code is actually alright. It works on devices but not in the emulator. Well thats 8 hours of my life i'm never getting back

Comment: I also meet this issue. The code works on devices but not in the emulator. Do you know why and how to let it work in emulator?

Comment: Another question, I think your ImageReader uses PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 but not ImageFormat.JPEG?  And the Bitmap uses Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, why you do not need to convert the format?